# Find Token by Index for bracket matching

Tags: java, antlr, syntax-highlighting, intellij-plugin, brackets

I'm extending the [ANTLR example plugin](https://github.com/antlr/jetbrains-plugin-sample), to add a bracket highlighting, so I've implemented the `PairedBraceMatcher` class from the intellij sdk, but I can't find a way to get a PsiElement from an index, this is what I've tried to far:

```java
public class SampleBraceMather implements PairedBraceMatcher {
    private static final BracePair[] PAIRS = {
            new BracePair(TokenIElementType.find((short) 327), TokenIElementType.find((short) 328), true)
    };


    @NotNull
    @Override
    public BracePair[] getPairs() {
        return PAIRS;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPairedBracesAllowedBeforeType(@NotNull IElementType lbraceType, @Nullable IElementType contextType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCodeConstructStart(PsiFile file, int openingBraceOffset) {
        return openingBraceOffset;
    }
}
```

and that actually works, but I'd like to don't hardcode the tokens index (since they change frequently), all I have so far is the `SampleLanguageParser.LBRACE` and `SampleLanguageParser.RBRACE` which are the ANTLR token indexes (11 and 12).

The token indexes (327 and 328) are defined only in the (generated) file `SampleLanguageLexer.interop` under the atn category, but I don't know how to get those values from there.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as solution

```java
    private static IElementType LBRACE;
    private static IElementType RBRACE;
    private static IElementType LBRACKET;
    private static IElementType RBRACKET;
    private static IElementType LPARENTHESIS;
    private static IElementType RPARENTHESIS;

    static {
        TokenIElementType.enumerate(type -> {
            if (type instanceof TokenIElementType) {
                TokenIElementType antlrToken = (TokenIElementType) type;
                switch (antlrToken.getANTLRTokenType()) {
                    case SampleLanguageParser.LBRACE:
                        LBRACE = type;
                        break;
                    case SampleLanguageParser.RBRACE:
                        RBRACE = type;
                        break;
                    case SampleLanguageParser.LBRACK:
                        LBRACKET = type;
                        break;
                    case SampleLanguageParser.RBRACK:
                        RBRACKET = type;
                        break;
                    case SampleLanguageParser.LPAREN:
                        LPARENTHESIS = type;
                        break;
                    case SampleLanguageParser.RPAREN:
                        RPARENTHESIS = type;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false; //Doesnt matter
        });
    }

    private static final BracePair[] PAIRS = {
            new BracePair(LBRACE, RBRACE, true), // {}
            new BracePair(LBRACKET, RBRACKET, false), // []
            new BracePair(LPARENTHESIS, RPARENTHESIS, false), // ()
    };
```

but it seems very verbose, any other solutions are welcome.